# Is the "Recent Activity" page still available?

Tags: support

I used to browse the "Recent Activity" page (/users/244297?tab=activity) which was available by clicking on the envelope icon next to my user name. But now this URL redirects to the "Profile" page. Is "Recent Activity" still available?

Comment: I want my envelope back :(

Comment: Funny, I just found that feature about a week ago and then it vanished.  I also liked being able to click on my login to see my profile.

Comment: For now: http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope

Comment: While changes are good sometimes, this change is really not good. They removed something good and made SO less user friendly. :/

Comment: Not a duplicate. This is asking if the page remains accessible; that one... is not actually a question, it's just a rant. But it implies "can we have the old link back."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is still available, just go to

`http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent`

Comment: Won't you leave any active link at the front page for us the weak-memory people?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it isn't working today. This is just so aggravating.