# Is there some way to see the old 'Recent Activity' screen?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, recent-activity, information-display

I like the new activity dropdown, but also like the old 'Recent Activity' page.  It only showed what happened since the last time I checked.  This was very convenient.  Now when I click on the various categories, I have huge lists, and am not sure where I had last checked.  This causes a lot of extra clicking around that is just a waste of time.  It's especially bad after a weekend off.

Please give us some way of getting to only the Recent Activity.

Comment: I actually don't like the new activity dropdown. I miss my envelope :(

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope

Comment: @Marti, I agree, didn't realize it was there, though it'd be nice if it was a feature request.

Comment: @Lance Roberts, I would actually classify it as a bug: something that used to work now no longer does. But when I tried to (re)tag it as such, I was threatened with unspecified Bad Things(TM).

Comment: @Marti: I agree that the "bug" tag was correct on your question, and I _love_ your closing "Take the bug tag off all you want, that doesn't change the fact that something that used to work now no longer does." However, I don't think this question is a duplicate. Here we really have a feature-request (of the sort: I'm capitulating; please a least give me the most important part of the functionality back).

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Ok, I can see that. My question is the bug report, to which the unwritten-so-far answer seems to be "sorry, you're SOL"; and this is the corresponding feature request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the "Recent Activity" page still available?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82631/is-the-recent-activity-page-still-available)